# Time lock... Invalid transaction

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

Been playing around with timelock transactions, made one to do a test went to do the spend and it was accepted by the network. However my transaction isnt confirming, I tried doing another one upping the miner fee but it still isnt confirming here is the transaction id if any bitcoin sluths feel like schooling a noob. Thanks in advance

204c60b879c02208cf52d762005e595859e09ea3dcb1cc0870a8d3c777672ad1

cefbf6877a17e7f69a2c822c9cd6ac163c593d25920ff22360cb0b6d800781e5
(Think this one got rejected as a double spend and can no longer be viewed)

Comment: Did your wallet abandon/forget 204c60? How much did you _bump_ fee in cefbf6?

Answer (score 0):

Your transaction [204c…2ad1](https://mempool.space/tx/204c60b879c02208cf52d762005e595859e09ea3dcb1cc0870a8d3c777672ad1) is not invalid, it is unconfirmed. It has a feerate of 5.02 ṩ/vB. We have not had a block that included transactions with feerates that low since at least [mid July](https://mempool.space/graphs/mempool#1m).

[image]

Your feerate is too low for your transaction to be selected into a block. Try using ~7 sat/vB.

Comment: thanks so much! was wondering what went wrong, what is the best way to increase the fee?

Comment: Hey, what software are you using?